# How to decode deflate block header from the deflate compression output result

Tags: zlib, deflate

I am trying to decode the header bits based on the output byte of `deflate` compression output.

```
char a[50] = "Hello";
z_stream defstream;
defstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
defstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
defstream.opaque = ZNULL;

defstream.avail_in = (uInt)strlen(a)+1;
defstream.next_in = (Bytef *)a;
defstream.avail_out = (uINt)sizeof(b);
defstream.next_out = (Bytef *)b;

deflateInit(&defstream, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);
deflate(&defstream, Z_FINISH);
deflateEnd(&defstream);

for (int i=0; i<strlen(b); i++) {
  printf("--- byte[%d]=%hhx\n", i, b[i]);
}
```

The result:

```
--- byte[0]=78
--- byte[1]=da
--- byte[2]=f3
```

and so on.

I just want to understand which bits are the 3-bit block header as described in `deflate` specification. First bit specifies the block final/BFINAL. Next two bits specify the BTYPE.

Based on this result, 0x78 - the first 3 bits are 000 which means BFINAL=0, BTYPE=00/no compression. But this seems not right to me. The BTYPE should specify either 01 or 10.

Am I missing out something here? Can someone please help?

Reference:
[deflate specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a zlib stream, not a raw deflate stream. So the `78 da` is the zlib header, not deflate compressed data. The deflate data starts with `f3`. The low three bits of that are `011`. The low `1` is BFINAL (this is the last block), and the `01` is BTYPE (fixed Huffman codes).